# knitr::spin Prevent all chunks for being executed

Tags: r, knitr

I'd like to document some R functions (not scripts) as html pages
using spin().
I thought of something like:

```
#' Test of rmarkdown  wit spin() for an html documented function
#' =======================================================
#+ eval=FALSE
test <- function(x,y)
{
  #' comment 1
  z <- x + y 
  #' comment 2
  z
}
```

But the `#+ eval=FALSE` applies to the first chunk only. Is there a way to prevent the actual execution of all chunks with on single command at the beginning?

Answer (score 4):

Set it globally:

```
#' Test of rmarkdown  wit spin() for an html documented function
#' =======================================================
#+ setup, include=FALSE
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = FALSE)
#+
test <- function(x,y) {
  # comment 1
  z <- x + y
  # comment 2
  z
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Should I put knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE)  at the end so that the option does not affect subsequent scripts?

Comment: @user2955884 Yes, although normally this is not a problem if you compile your documents in separate R sessions, like what RStudio does.